# Split 1 long column into 2 shorter, which ref the 2 columns of another table

Tags: r, split, tibble

PLease help to guide me how to code in R. Thanks

**Table 1 original**

| Nation | index |
| --- | --- |
| USA | 1.2 |
| ENG | 0.9 |
| FRC | 2 |
| RUS | 1.5 |

**then reference to Group1 and Group 2 column in table 2**

| Group1 | Group2 | Pop | Pop |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | ENG | 1000 | 502 |
| RUS | FRC | 1200 | 200 |

**To achieve Table 1 like this**

| Group1 | Group2 | Index G1 | Index 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | ENG | 1.2 | 0.9 |
| RUS | FRC | 1.5 | 2 |

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tribble(~Nation, ~index,
"USA",  1.2,
"ENG",  0.9,
"FRC",  2,
"RUS",  1.5)

df2 <- tribble(~Group1, ~Group2, ~Pop1, ~Pop2,
"USA",  "ENG",  1000,   502,
"RUS",  "FRC",  1200,   200)

df2 %>% left_join(df1, by = c("Group1" = "Nation")) %>%
  select(-Pop1, -Pop2) %>%
  left_join(df1, by = c("Group2" = "Nation")) %>% 
  rename(`Index G1` = index.x, `Index G2` = index.y)

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  Group1 Group2 `Index G1` `Index G2`
  <chr>  <chr>       <dbl>      <dbl>
1 USA    ENG           1.2        0.9
2 RUS    FRC           1.5        2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reshape the second dataset into long format, join it with first dataset and get it back in wide format. Using @nyk's data :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Group'), values_to = 'Nation') %>%
  left_join(df1, by = 'Nation') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = c(Nation, index))

#   Pop1  Pop2 Nation_Group1 Nation_Group2 index_Group1 index_Group2
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>         <chr>                <dbl>        <dbl>
#1  1000   502 USA           ENG                    1.2          0.9
#2  1200   200 RUS           FRC                    1.5          2
```

If you don't need `Pop` columns in the final output you can add `select(-starts_with('Pop'))`.